# Vagrant SSH error

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

When i do

```
vagrant ssh
```

i get

```
Administrator@WIN-NJMOO12L1J5 MINGW64 ~/Homestead (master)
$ vagrant sshssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

and i've tried booting with GUI and nothing is changed when i try to start with it, so i have probably done something wrong.

and i've seen that people say that i have to enable Intel® Virtualization Technology but my host doesnt alow that, so i dont know how to fix that.

Specs:

```
Windows Server 2012 r2
64bit
Ram 1gb
intel xeon e5 2697 v3 2.60 ghz
```

Vagrant file:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
# The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
# For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
# https://docs.vagrantup.com.

# Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
# boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
config.vm.box = "laravel/homestead"

# The url from where the 'config.vm.box' box will be fetched if it
# doesn't already exist on the user's system.
config.vm.box_url = "./virtualbox.box"

# Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
# within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
# accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
# config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

# Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
# using a specific IP.
# config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

# Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
# Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
# your network.
# config.vm.network "public_network"

# Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
# the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
# the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
# argument is a set of non-required options.
# config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

# Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
# backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
# Example for VirtualBox:
#
Vagrant.configure("1") do |config|
config.vm.boot_mode = :gui
end
#
#   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
#   vb.memory = "1024"
# end
#
# View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
# information on available options.

# Define a Vagrant Push strategy for pushing to Atlas. Other push strategies
# such as FTP and Heroku are also available. See the documentation at
# https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/push/atlas.html for more information.
# config.push.define "atlas" do |push|
#   push.app = "YOUR_ATLAS_USERNAME/YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME"
# end

# Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
# Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
# documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
# config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
#   sudo apt-get update
#   sudo apt-get install -y apache2
# SHELL
end
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Show your `Vagrantfile`. also, how did you create the machine? only `vagrant up`? or anything else?

Comment: I created it by: vagrant box add laravel/homestead ./virtualbox.box then vagrant up

Comment: What was the output of `vagrant up`?  
What is the output of `vagrant status` in the directory in which the `Vagrantfile` is located?

Comment: Vagrant up gives:                                                                                            $ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> default: VirtualBox VM is already running.

Comment: Vagrant status gives
Current machine states:

default                   running (virtualbox)

The VM is running. To stop this VM, you can run `vagrant halt` to
shut it down forcefully, or you can run `vagrant suspend` to simply
suspend the virtual machine. In either case, to restart it again,
simply run `vagrant up`.

Comment: and the file is in C:\Users\Administrator